# How to robocopy with progress logged to console only?

Tags: robocopy

I want to run RoboCopy that will update the console with % progress but not clutter the log file with % progress.

The following RoboCopy command will perform the desired copy and append logging information the log file.

```
RoboCopy <source> <dest> /log+:<log file> /tee
```

The problem is the log file is cluttered with % progress updates. Therefore I need to changed the command to this:

```
RoboCopy <source> <dest> /log+:<log file> /tee /np
```

Now the problem is I don't getting any % progress updates on screen.

I've read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx a few times now and can't find a switch(es) I need. Am I missing something or is what I want to achieve not possible?

Comment: Do you have to use only builtin tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nobody has answered this for so long, I thought I'd suggest a couple of things.

If you are using batch scripts, it should not be too difficult to use [**sed**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) to strip out the unwanted progress information from the log file.  I'm not experienced enough with it to give you a solution using it without spending some time on it though.

There is a single .exe file version of `sed` in [**UnxUtils**](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) (with a slightly more up to date version in the update zip).

Another option would be to use [**XXCOPY**](http://www.xxcopy.com/xcpymain.htm) instead of `Robocopy`.  It has [**a truly ridiculous number of switches**](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy98.htm) (over 230), which allows you to do whatever you want.  You have to spend a whole evening choosing which ones you want to use.  It also has a GUI progress dialogue box, if you would prefer to use that.

There is a free version for personal use, which cannot be used for automated scripting, as you need to interactively follow prompts, unlike the paid-for version.

[image: XXCOPY]

Another alternative is [**RichCopy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RichCopy), which has a GUI which would can use to choose your options. It can then give you the command-line of you operation for use in batch scripts.

[image: RichCopy]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** use just /TEE and let it log the 'noise', otherwise you'll not see any progress.
Then use sed, as first suggested to clean the logfile as follows:

```
 sed -i.bak "s/\x0d.\*\x0d.\*$//" logfile.txt
```

Remove the `.bak` if you don't want an unfixed backup. `sed` is available for windows here, and works fine, at least for single* line use.

[http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

`sed` command in Unix `bash/cshell` scripts are often spread over multiple lines, adding more flexibility and complexity. I don't expect those type of `sed` command to work with Windows `cmd` scripts, but `sed` is still useful under Windows.

Comment: +1 Isn't there a way to pipe `stdout` through `sed` directly?

Comment: of course you can pipe through sed, that would however remove the progress information from the console display as well as possibly the logfile...

Comment: Of course, but I thought maybe the `tee` command could be used instead of Robocopy's `/TEE` switch, but I have just realised that it is part of `TCC/LE` and not a standard `CMD` command.  It is available in `PowerShell` though.

Comment: actually.. it still writes the progress mess to the logfile! So is the exact opposite of what is wanted. I just tested with: robocopy . tst /log:n:\tst.log /tee | sed "s/\x0d.*\x0d.*$//"

Comment: tee is also available from gnuwin32.. but would have the same problem ;) http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm